# Время из значения списка

Tags: python

Как получить номер секунды из `[20210901100621750]` ? В данном примере ответ 21.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`20210901100621750` - это `2021-09-01T10:06:21.750`. Не самая популярная версия записи, но допустимая по iso. В любом случае, очень странно, что она в виде числа а не строки.

Но раз уж такая попалась, а нужны только секунды, просто делим её и всё:

https://ideone.com/A8aUS9

```
x = 20210901100621750
print(x // 1000 % 100)
```

```
21
```

А как сконвертировать в дату, уже написали в соседнем ответе.

Answer (score 2):

Вот думаю вроде этого вы имеете в виду:

```
timelist = [20210901100621750]
time_convert = str(timelist[0])
seconds = datetime.strptime(time_convert, '%Y%m%d%H%M%S%f').second # = 21
```

Это если это всё же такой своеобразный формат записи даты и времени, а не `timestamp`.

Comment: https://ideone.com/5dvrT7